# unmarshling error when send the format date in web service request

Tags: web-services, jaxb

when I send the date in below format from the soap ui . I am getting unmarshiling error
   2018-03-14

wsdl schema is

this problme is occour when i am sending this request from one server to other server means my first server route to the request to another server. if I am directly send this request to second(another) server message goes to succuessfully.

error log :

22:35:09,441 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-jbossbillingserver/172.19.54.54:8180-1) Interceptor for {service}BillingServiceImplService#{service}terminateService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error:
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:907)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:711)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
        at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; ]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:857)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:896)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:894)
E486: Pattern not found: terminateService update status date is

Comment: <updateStatusDate>2018-03-14</updateStatusDate> schema is    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="updateStatusDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>

Comment: What happens if you change type to xs:date?

Comment: If i will change the xs:date it will given unmarshling error

Comment: your sample xml and code you are trying..